# Time spent in a state for ergodic Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I think this question is trivial but I don't know much about Markov chains. Given an ergodic Markov chain with a finite state-space, is the proportion of the time spent in state $i$ (in the long-time limit) equal to the probability of the state $i$ in the stationary distribution? I'm pretty sure the answer is yes but I'm looking for a theorem that gives this result formally.

Comment: You are studying $t^{-1}\int_{0}^{t}P(X(s)=i) ds$ which converges (due to the law of the large number) to its limit $E[1_{X=i}]=\mu(i)$ where $\mu$ is the stationary distribution.

Comment: Specifically I'm interested in a two-state system, $i_k = 0,1$ where $k = 1, \dots , N$ where $N$ is the length of the sequence.
So I'm essentially asking if $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k = 1}^N \mathbb{1}_{i_k=j}$ converges for $N \to \infty$ to $\mu(j)$.

Answer (score -1):

I found the theorem that I needed here (Theorem 1.10.2) http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s110.pdf.  Setting f = \mathbb{1}_{X_k = j} yields the result.